# angular.js direct access of properties vs this.get()

Tags: javascript, angular

The legacy codebase I'm working with involves some angular.js bits like:

```
export const UserModel = NgModel.extend({
    _name: 'UserModel',
    defaults: {
        name: null,
        emails: null,
    },
    parse: function(data) { [removed for brevity] },
    getPrimaryEmail: function() {
        return this.get('emails').getPrimaryEmailAddress();
    },
```

My question is about the body of the `getPrimaryEmail` method. What I would like to know is if there's any difference between writing `this.emails` and `this.get('emails')`?

In some parts of the codebase I see direct access (like `this.emails`) but other bits use getters (like  `this.get('emails')`). What's the difference?

Comment: Angular or AngularJS?

Comment: AngularJS  @Phix